# How to send API request json body in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, json, karate

Can anyone help me to send json request in one line ??
Example

```
{
  "benefitPlanIDs": [
    {
      "benefitPlanID": "011748abc",
      "benefitPlanPlatform": "abc"
    }
  ],
  "clientId": "abc",
  "dateOfService": "2017-01-01",
  "language": "English",
  "searchPhrase": "Digital",
  "session": "3nopmolkgjanbe2x2ddttlua"
}
```

I need to pass this as 
 Given User hits "/end points" 
    When User make Search in request

```
Examples: 
  | searchPhrase |
  | "out"        |
```

Right now I am passing as 
When User enters request details as following, ,  ,,, ,

```
Examples: 
  | BenefitPlanPlatform | BenefitPlanID     | ClientId | Session                    | DateOfService | Language  | searchPhrase |
  | "abc"              | "0117482abc" | "abc"  | "3nopmolkgjanbe2x2ddttlua" | "2017-01-01"  | "English" | "out"        |
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi you can use multiline argument (docstring) for this:

https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#doc-strings
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/README.md#multi-line-expressions

**Your step definition:**

Here you pass the json between **""" and """**

```
Given a blog post named "Random" with Markdown body
"""
       { "benefitPlanIDs": [ { "benefitPlanID": "011748abc", "benefitPlanPlatform": "abc" } ], "clientId": "abc", "dateOfService": "2017-01-01", "language": "English", "searchPhrase": "Digital", "session": "3nopmolkgjanbe2x2ddttlua" }
"""
```

**Your step definition** :

the text is retrieved in the step definition as an argument,so if your step definition is like:

```
Given('the user is {string}', function(a){
  console.log(a) 
});
```

change it to:

```
Given('the user is {string}', function(a,b){
  console.log(a) 
  console.log(b) 
});
```

You will have the docstring as the last argument parameter 'b'

Comment: Just fyi, in Karate, you cannot define a custom function like you do in Cucumber, as described in your answer.

Comment: @djangofan that was for cucumber , https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/README.md#multi-line-expressions the correct implementation can be seen here

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using Java in your testing framework. You have two ways of achieving it.

**Option 1:**

Try using [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) framework. If you use Java and want to do easy API testing.

**Option 2:**

Table is an object with fields named accordingly to table header. Basically you need to [serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607444/how-to-serialize-object-to-json) them to json in a way that is suitable. You can use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library for serialization.